# How can I get a sum of sums using MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to get the total (sum) of the `totalHoursForYear` value. Here is my current aggregation:

```js
const byYear = await this.workHistoryModel.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$year',
      history: {
        $push: '$$ROOT'
      },
      totalHoursForYear: {
        $sum: {
          $add: [
            { $multiply: ['$eightHourDays', 8] },
            { $multiply: ['$tenHourDays', 10] },
            { $multiply: ['$twelveHourDays', 12] },
          ]
        }
      },
    }
  },
]);
```

Now I need to get a sum of the `totalHoursForYear` to get the total for all years. Is this possible? I can't seem to get the syntax correct. When I attempt to add another sum:

```js
$group: {
  ...,
  totalHours: {
    $sum: {
      $add: '$totalHoursForYear'
    },
    $push: '$$ROOT'
  }
}
```

I get an error: "The field 'totalHours' must specify one accumulator"

Comment: I think `$sum: "$totalHoursForYear"` should work.  Remove `$add`.

Comment: I get the same error: `The field 'totalHours' must specify one accumulator`

Comment: Are you adding the *totalHours*  field in the same `$group` stage? or could you show the pipeline with *totalHours*?

Comment: its working fine https://mongoplayground.net/p/k9tfvj8mFtJ

Comment: @styvane Yes, I"m adding `totalHours` in the `$group` stage

Comment: @varman, Yes, the `totalHoursForYear` sum is correct. What I need to do is sum `totalHoursForYear` across all years.

Comment: group it again https://mongoplayground.net/p/VyskCc1juy_

Comment: @varman. The calculation works, but I lose all of my previous fields in the output. How can I output everything together? `$project`?

Comment: As you did already, you can push your data to an array `"$push":"$$ROOT"`

Comment: I tried that, and I get my original error: `The field 'totalHours' must specify one accumulator`

Comment: does https://mongoplayground.net/p/2DCOXKLZDl7 help you?

Comment: I will make this as an answer, if anything goes wrong, let me know. I will try to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need total sum, you can do another `$group` with `_id:null` which means to consider all documents

With your script, add the following to get the total and get the same structure.

```
{
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$totalHoursForYear"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      _id: "$data._id",
      history: "$data.history",
      totalHoursForYear: "$data.totalHoursForYear",
      _id: "$$REMOVE",
      data: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2DCOXKLZDl7)**

Comment: Thanks @varman that works. I sincerely appreciate your help!

Comment: @Brandon u r welcome. there are multiple ways to do this, try to use `$facet` for a practice

Comment: Interesting. I'm usually on the UI side of things, but the aggregation pipeline is really powerful, granted you know how to combine the operators and access the values.

Comment: @Brandon Compass has an [aggregation pipeline builder](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/aggregation-pipeline-builder), that could help you next time.

Comment: @HanielBaez Thanks. I'll have to check that out.